# suppress clang-tidy -Wdocumentation "empty paragraph" errors

Tags: doxygen, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

I can't seem to find where I might be able to suppress these specific errors
or why they are even registering in the first place.

`error: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command`

Here is the documentation that I have that is generating this error:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------
///
/// @brief functionThatModifiesSomething
///
/// @param[in] param1
/// @param[in] param2
///
//-----------------------------------------------------------
void functionThatModifiesSomething(uint32_t param1, uint32_t param2);
```

I only noticed this because I am finally turning on some of these warnings and I'm cleaning up as I go.

After seeing the warning, I don't understand why it is registering an error when the @param is not an empty paragraph. Any thoughts? Can I suppress this *flavor* of documentation warning somehow?

Here is the full error:

```
./path/to/somefile.hpp:570:21: error: empty paragraph passed to '@param'     command [-Werror,-Wdocumentation]
/// @param param1
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

We are using Doxygen as our documentation format.

Comment: Open clang bug for this is at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/60315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@param` expects a description to follow the parameter name, which is missing in the above.
So a possible fix may be:

```
/// @param[in] param1 Description #1
/// @param[in] param2 Description #2
```

See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam for `@param` documentation.

Clang's documentation warnings are enabled with `-Wdocumentation`, which is disabled by default. There's a whole bunch of documentation warning from different kinds, which are all enabled by `-Wdocumentation`, but unfortunately you can't opt out from individual warnings such as the "empty paragraph passed to @command" warning.

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation! Sad I can't disable it without disabling them all though. \*sigh\*